# Calculating the min and max and deleting them

Tags: java

so for my project this is what i need to do In the sport of diving, seven judges award a score between 0 and 10 where each score may be a floating-point value. The highest and lowest scores are thrown out and the remaining scores are added together. The sum is then multiplied by the degree of difficulty for that dive. The degree of difficulty ranges from 1.2 to 4.8 points. The total is then multiplied by 0.6 to determine the diver’s score.

Write a program that prompts the user for the degree of difficulty and seven judges’ scores and outputs the overall score for that dive. The program should use an array to store the seven scores. The program should also ensure that all inputs are within the allowable data ranges.

Sample output:

Enter the degree of difficulty for the dive (1.2 - 4.8): 7.3

Invalid difficulty. Please re-enter: 1.5

Enter the score for each judge (0.0 - 10.0):

Enter score for judge 1 : 12.3

Invalid score. Please re-enter: 14.5

Invalid score. Please re-enter: 8

Enter score for judge 2 : 7.5

Enter score for judge 3 : 8.5

Enter score for judge 4 : 8

Enter score for judge 5 : 7

Enter score for judge 6 : 8

Enter score for judge 7 : 7.5

Score for the dive is 35.1

What I am stuck on is how to get a code that will automatically take out the min and max...

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Random rng = new Random();

        int[] values = new int[1000];
        // Fill it up
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            values[i] = rng.nextInt(100);
        }

        // Find min
        /*int indexOfMin = 0;
        int indexOfMax = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            if(values[i] < values[indexOfMin]) {
            indexOfMin = i;
            }
            if (values[i] > values[indexOfMax]) {
                indexOfMax = i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Minimum is at index " + indexOfMin + " with         value " + values[indexOfMin]);      
    System.out.println("Maximum is at index " + indexOfMax + " with value " + values[indexOfMax]);      
     */

    double[] difficulty = new double[1];
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int d = 0; d < difficulty.length; d++) {
        System.out.println(" Enter Difficulty " + d + ":" );
        difficulty[d] = keyboard.nextDouble();

        while (difficulty[d] < 1.2 || difficulty[d] > 4.8) {
            System.out.println(" Bad value. Try again: ");;
            difficulty[d] = keyboard.nextDouble();
        }

        Scanner keyboard1 = new Scanner(System.in);
            double[] scores = new double[7];
            for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(" Enter score " + i + ":" );
                scores[i] = keyboard1.nextDouble();

                while (scores[i] < 0.0 || scores[i] > 10.0) {
                    System.out.println(" Bad value. Try again: ");;
                    scores[i] = keyboard1.nextDouble();


                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the indecOfMin and indexOfMax are // out of the code because I think i have it wrong or that it doesnt apply/help with this project

Comment: Why not check that the code is correct? I don't see any problem with the logic from looking at it.

Comment: because it doesnt relate to the problem. Its not the right code. It just spits out some random numbers that have nothing to do with the users input

Comment: *"What I am stuck on is how to get a code that will automatically take out the min and max"*, how does the min and max functionality in question not relate to the problem? It's random because you are doing it on a randomly made array, just use it on your input items instead.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of searching for the min or max, you can sort the array of values, and then pull the max off of one end of the array, and the min off of the other end.

For the sorting, you can use a bubble sort:

```
public double[] bubbleSort(double[] array) {
    int numberOfItems = array.length;

    for (int pass=1; pass != numberOfItems; pass++) {
        for (int index=0; index != numberOfItems-pass; index++) {
            if (array[index] < array[index+1]) {
               temp = array[index];
               array[index] = array[index+1];
               array[index+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

That will sort the array from least to greatest, and return it.

Then you can pull from the array like this:

```
int maxIndex = array.length - 1;
double max = array[maxIndex];
double min = array[0];
```

You may have to make some minor changes to implement it into your own code.

Comment: i don't know how to do that though

Comment: I adjusted the answer for you